# OpenVPN on Ubuntu 14.04: Auto Connect on startup

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, autostart

There are a lot of topics concerning this.
OpenVPN Auto Connection by putting the conf file to /etc/openvpn just doesnt work.
When using the Authentification type "password" an easy way to make it work is:

adding a shell script to /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d (which is executed automatically on network acitivty)

```
#/bin/bash
REQUIRED_CONNECTION1_NAME="wlan0"
REQUIRED_CONNECTION2_NAME="eth0"
VPN_CONNECTION_NAME="myVPN"

activ_con=$(nmcli con status | grep "${REQUIRED_CONNECTION1_NAME}\|${REQUIRED_CONNECTION2_NAME}")
activ_vpn=$(nmcli con status | grep "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}")
if [ "${activ_con}" -a ! "${activ_vpn}" ];
then
    nmcli con up id "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}"
fi
```

since this causes an error saying the vpn-secret is missing, you have to change the connection config in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myVPN
setting

```
 password-flags=0
```

and adding

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=myPassword
```

Now it works fine.

My question is:
Is there a way to not put the password in clear text to a conf file. I know its only readable by root but cant i put like a key to it?

Comment: I only just started with Ask Ubuntu, so please forgive this response for being a "solution" rather than a comment. I came to ask a similar question to yours, after a few hours of research I stumbled upon this neat liike OpenVPN plugin. [openvpn-auth-file](https://github.com/yarikdot/openvpn-auth-file) I'm still trying to get it to work, but it looks promising. Please note that I am not the author of this script, I'm only passing along the knowledge. Good Luck, hope it works for you.